# jquery ui toggle button to trigger setTimeout function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a toggle button which should run a function when toggel is pressed.
and function should stop when toggle is off.But whenever toggle is turned on, it should run function constantly.

JSBIN Try:
http://jsbin.com/AbIzuNO/1/edit

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check">Toggle</label>
```

**JS:**

```
var Autoreload;

$("#check").button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-circle-triangle-s"
    }
}).click(function () {
    var iconClass;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        iconClass = "ui-icon-circle-triangle-e";
        Autoreload = setTimeout(function () {
            //Run somefunction here constantly untill cleared
            //$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
            //  some success calls
            //});
            console.log("Running");
        }, 100);

    } else {
        iconClass = "ui-icon-circle-triangle-s";
        clearTimeout(Autoreload);
    }
    $(this).button("option", {
        icons: {
            primary: iconClass
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

- `setTimeout` to `setInterval`
- `clearTimeout` to `clearInterval`